# MySQL multiple tables in the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've been given a MySQL database of college alumni that records what occupations students had after they graduated. There are three tables that concern me (I've simplified them):

1. Students (StudentID, GraduationYear)
2. StudentOccupations (StudentID, OccupationName, OccupationChange1, OccupationChange2)
3. OccupationsClassified (OccupationName, Sector, Status)

I'm making a web form so that people within the college can query these tables. In particular they want to select a graduation year range and an occupation name to ask something like "How many people who graduated between 1970 and 1980 have worked as a School teacher?"

My SQL for this is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `Students`.`StudentID`) AS `Students`
FROM `Students`
INNER JOIN `StudentOccupations` ON `Students`.`StudentID`=`StudentOccupations`.`StudentID`
INNER JOIN `OccupationsClassified` ON  `StudentOccupations`.`OccupationName`=`OccupationsClassified`.`OccupationName` 
WHERE `Students`.`GraduationYear` BETWEEN 1970 AND 1980
AND 'School teacher' 
IN (`StudentOccupations`.`OccupationName`,`StudentOccupations`.OccupationChange1`, `StudentOccupations`.`OccupationChange2`);
```

That query seems to work okay, but they also want to search by sector, and ask "How many people who graduated between 1970 and 1980 have worked in the Education sector?" I was hoping to start this query with the first few lines from the above query because I can then construct the query with PHP conditionals (if this element was selected in the form then add this MySQL clause etc). I can't work out how to, though.

This is my latest effort (it's not counting records yet, and it's departed from the above query):

```
SELECT  `StudentOccupations`.`OccupationName`,`StudentOccupations`.`OccupationChange1`, `StudentOccupations`.`OccupationChange2`
FROM `StudentOccupations`
INNER JOIN `Students` ON `StudentOccupations`.`WebID` = `Students`.`WebID`
INNER JOIN `OccupationsClassified` ON `StudentOccupations`.`OccupationName`=`OccupationsClassified`.`OccupationName`
WHERE `Students`.`GraduationYear` BETWEEN 1970 AND 1980
AND EXISTS (SELECT `OccupationsClassified`.`OccupationName` FROM `OccupationsClassified` WHERE `OccupationClassified`.`Sector` = 'Education')
```

As you can see, I'm struggling a bit! Has anyone got any ideas how I can filter results by occupation sector?

Comment: This may be a silly question, but why not drop the `AND EXISTS...` and just add `AND \`OccupationsClassified\`.\`Sector\` = 'Education'` to the second `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Good point. The EXISTS was left over from a more convoluted query I was playing around with, and I lost sight of simplicity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join OccupationsClassified on all Occupations like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT `Students`.`StudentID`) AS `Students`
FROM `Students`
  INNER JOIN `StudentOccupations` ON `Students`.`StudentID` = `StudentOccupations`.`StudentID`
  LEFT JOIN `OccupationsClassified` initialOc
    ON `StudentOccupations`.`OccupationName` = `OccupationsClassified`.`OccupationName`
  LEFT JOIN `OccupationsClassified` secondOc
    ON `StudentOccupations`.`OccupationChange1` = `OccupationsClassified`.`OccupationName`
  LEFT JOIN `OccupationsClassified` thirdOc
    ON `StudentOccupations`.`OccupationChange2` = `OccupationsClassified`.`OccupationName`
WHERE
  `Students`.`GraduationYear` BETWEEN 1970 AND 1980
  AND 'Education' IN (initialOc.Sector, secondOc.Sector, thirdOc.Sector);
```

or as you already have a `DISTINCT` in your `COUNT` you could do

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT `Students`.`StudentID`) AS `Students`
FROM `Students`
  INNER JOIN `StudentOccupations` ON `Students`.`StudentID` = `StudentOccupations`.`StudentID`
  INNER JOIN `OccupationsClassified` ON `OccupationsClassified`.`OccupationName` IN
                                        (`StudentOccupations`.`OccupationName`, `StudentOccupations`.`OccupationChange1`, `StudentOccupations`.`OccupationChange2`)
WHERE
  `Students`.`GraduationYear` BETWEEN 1970 AND 1980
  AND `OccupationsClassified`.`Sector` = 'Education';
```

Comment: Wow - that was just what I was looking for! Useful having both answers. I knew it was possible to do something like this, but I just didn't have the knowledge to do it. Thanks so much for taking the time to write it up!